# Why VARCHAR data sorted as if there was a space appended on the end

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2017, I encountered a query that was sorting on a VARCHAR column returning results in a different order than I expected, namely a string followed by a tab came *before* just the bare string.  Further investigation showed that it was behaving as if the bare string had a space on the end.

Experimenting further, given the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'a' + CHAR(33)),
    (2, 'a   '),
    (3, 'a  '),
    (4, 'a '),
    (5, 'a' + CHAR(31)),
    (6, 'a')
)v(rownum, text)
ORDER BY text
```

I would have expected the results to be:

| rownum | text |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 'a' |
| 5 | 'a(31)' |
| 4 | 'a(sp)' |
| 3 | 'a(sp)(sp)' |
| 2 | 'a(sp)(sp)(sp)' |
| 1 | 'a(33)' |

But instead it was:

| rownum | text |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 'a(31)' |
| 3 | 'a(sp)(sp)' |
| 4 | 'a(sp)' |
| 2 | 'a(sp)(sp)(sp)' |
| 6 | 'a' |
| 1 | 'a(33)' |

So it seems as if it treats 'a'+(no spaces) and 'a'+(any amount of spaces) as if they were all equivalent.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because SQL Server follows ANSI standard string comparison rules, so 'a' and 'a ' are *equal*.  eg

```
SELECT *, rank() over (order by text) rank 
FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'a' + CHAR(33)),
    (2, 'a   '),
    (3, 'a  '),
    (4, 'a '),
    (5, 'a' + CHAR(31)),
    (6, 'a')
)v(rownum, text)
ORDER BY text
```

outputs

```
rownum      text rank
----------- ---- --------------------
5           a   1
3           a    2
4           a    2
2           a    2
6           a    2
1           a!   6

(6 rows affected)
```

And the order in which rows are returned that are equal in the ORDER BY clause is undefined, and plan-dependent.

Comment: Based on this answer I searched for what the ANSI standard rules were on this.  Found https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240037/why-pad-instead-of-trim-when-comparing-strings which points to a copy of the spec. Paragraph 8.2.3.a says that comparisons act as if they're padding a shorter string to the length of the longer string.  So in my case it would effectively pad all the strings with spaces to make them 4 characters.  Definitely not what I would have expected given my C/C++/C#/etc. background.

Answer (score 3):

> So it seems as if it treats 'a'+(no spaces) and 'a'+(any amount of spaces) as if they were all equivalent.

This is *exactly* what is going on. When dealing with equality operations SQL Server effectively ignores trailing spaces, so `''` and `'    '` are seen as equal, and so too are `'a'`, `'a '` and `'a   '`.

As a result the `ORDER BY` you have, `ORDER BY text`, isn't deterministic; you have 4 rows that all have the same value. This means that when you run the query the 4 rows with the same value are returned in an *arbitrary* order. If you wanted to ensure you ordered values with the least trailing spaces first then you could add `DATALENGTH(text)` to the `ORDER BY`, as unlike `LEN` it *does* include trailing spaces in its calculation:

```sql
SELECT rownum,
       text,
       DATALENGTH(text) AS Characters
FROM (VALUES(1, 'a' + CHAR(33)),
            (2, 'a   '),
            (3, 'a  '),
            (4, 'a '),
            (5, 'a' + CHAR(31)),
            (6, 'a'))v(rownum, text)
ORDER BY text,
         DATALENGTH(text);
```

To get the order you were expecting, you'd want to order the data by it's binary value:

```sql
SELECT rownum,
       text,
       DATALENGTH(text) AS Characters,
       CONVERT(varbinary(4),text)
FROM (VALUES(1, 'a' + CHAR(33)),
            (2, 'a   '),
            (3, 'a  '),
            (4, 'a '),
            (5, 'a' + CHAR(31)),
            (6, 'a'))v(rownum, text)
ORDER BY CONVERT(varbinary(4),text);
```